# Check if a physicsbody is touching another without waiting for didBeginContact

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I know you can detect contact collisions using `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, but can you check if a physicsbody is **currently** touching another physicsbody?

I need this for checking which area in the scene is still available to put an item (eg. pick a random spot, and if there's something in the way, pick another random spot).

There's this function:

```
/* Returns an array of all SKPhysicsBodies currently in contact with this one */
- (NSArray *)allContactedBodies;
```

But it doesn't appear to return anything useful until after the next update of creating the node.

Comment: what is the shape of the body you are adding?

Comment: It's a circle with range: `SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to iterate manually through all the nodes and check if the two circles intersect a point.

Since you said that the radius of the circles will differ each time, you have to keep track of it. One method is to use the user data of the node.

```
[node.userData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0] forKey:@"radius"];
```

Then you can find if there are intersecting circles in the following way.

```
-(BOOL)checkPointForNode:(CGPoint)point withRadius:(CGFloat)nodeRadius
{
    for (SKNode* child in [self children])
    {
        NSNumber *childRadius = child.userData[@"radius"];
        if (childRadius != nil)
        {
            CGFloat diffX = point.x - child.position.x;
            CGFloat diffY = point.y - child.position.y;

            CGFloat distance = sqrtf(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

            CGFloat sumRadius = nodeRadius + childRadius.floatValue;

            if (distance <= sumRadius)
            {
                return  YES;
            }

        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The function returns `YES` if there is a circle within the boundary of the circle you are going to add. This means you cannot add a new node without touching another node. Otherwise it returns `NO`. This means you can add a new node without touching any other nodes.

Comment: In that case, this function should be recursive (due to nodes being able to have child nodes).

Comment: you didn't talk about nested child nodes in your question. i thought the whole point was to avoid putting nodes on top of other nodes

Comment: you can make it recursive. its quite simple.

Comment: Correct, that was just an afterthought in case somebody else stumbles upon this code :)